# How to disable notifications from automated "shortcuts"?

Tags: ios, automation, shortcuts-app

How can I disable notifications from iOS "Automation" "shortcuts"?

Is there a way to disable (or manage at all) notifications from my shortcuts? I have "Automation" shortcuts which turn on the phone screen and I really don't need or want notifications for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Apple has not added that functionality (yet) as of iOS 14.

Even if you go into Settings » Notifications, there are no Notification settings for Shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way but it requires Screen Time to be enabled.

You need to go to **Settings** ▶ **Screen Time**, search for **See All Activity**, scroll down to Notification section (it’s shown only when you got 1 or more notifications from shortcuts after enabling Screen Time), and there you can manage shortcuts notification permissions, style, etc.

Comment: I tried this, it did not work reliably.